# prevent redirecting to https and URI hacks nginx reverse proxy

Tags: redirect, docker, nginx, reverse-proxy

I have setted up a reverse proxy on my server with nginx inside docker, and since then all request are redirecting to https although i didn't set all locations to https redirection.

Basically what i want is to be able to serve both https and http with the reverse proxy.
In addition i want to be able to redirect to different URI dynamically, for example i want to set all routes of /bla2/foo/bar to be redirected to only what comes after /bla2
what i tried to get here is that whenever accessing to example.com/bla2/foo/bar it should redirect it to example.com/foo/bar without the **bla2** section...

1. Is it possible on the same configuration file?
2. what can cause my server to redirect all request to https

**This is my server nginx.conf**

```
 server {
        listen   443;
        ssl    on;
        ssl_certificate    /etc/ssl/example.com.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key    /etc/ssl/example.com.key;


        listen     80;
        server_name  example.com;

        location /bla/bla {
                proxy_pass http://example.com:3980/foo/bar1;
        }

        **location /bla2/**{
               # proxy_pass http://example.com:3004;
                return 301 http://example.com:3004$request_uri;

                proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
                proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
                proxy_redirect off;
                proxy_http_version 1.1;
                proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";

                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        }

        location /app3 {
                rewrite ^/app3(.*) /$1 break;
                proxy_pass http://example.com:1236/app3;
        }
}
```

I want to be able to get directly content of **http://example.com:3004** if i put it in the browser without any redirection to https.
Only if i try access **example.com/bla2** i want it to be required https instead of http, and to be redirected to different path.

Comment: What is the issue right now? Also what is running on 3004? NodeJS?

Comment: i have 2 different issues, one is the all http redirected to http no matter if i point to an app, and the other the routing problem as i mentioned above. i just editted the content i hope it is clearer now. Yes the apps are node js apps

Comment: If you directly access in browser `http://example.com:3004/` and that redirects to https then it could be only because your app is sending that redirect. Also make sure you clear browser cache

Comment: Does the configuration I put are alligned to what I want ?

Comment: From the looks of it, i don't see any issue and it should do what you want

Comment: What about the second case where I wanted to forward all request to the same uri excluding sub path. Example.com/bla/Foo/bar to example.com:3000/Foo/bar, in this example I removed the /bla but kept all that comes after it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/156577/discussion-between-tarun-lalwani-and-user4860092).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use regular expression and capture groups for this

```
location ~* /bla2/(.*) {
    return 301 http://example.com:3004$1$is_args$args;
}
```

Another way of doing it would be just use rewrite

```
rewrite ^/bla2/(.*)$ http://example.com:3004/$1 redirect;
```

If you want to transparently proxy it to the `example.com:3004` removing `/bla2` then you should use

```
location /bla2/ {
   proxy_pass http://example.com:3004/;
}
```

The trailing slash `/` in `/bla2/` and `http://example.com:3004/` is very important here

Comment: if you don't mind to add a third options without using the redirect, so I be able to accept the answer, since eventually I choosed an option that don't use redirection, i think you know what i mean

Comment: @user4860092, check now